# Wio Node setup failed

Tags: hardware

To setup *Wio Node*, I installed the *Wio* Android app.
The procedure doesn't end when I try to connect Wio Device like the image.

[image: Wio connection wizard screenshot]

After that I installed [wio-cli](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/wio-cli) and [a driver](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/software/Mac_OSX_VCP_Driver.zip) for Mac.

Then logged in.

```
 % wio login
1.) Global Server (New)[https://us.wio.seeed.io]
2.) Chinese Server [https://cn.wio.seeed.io]
3.) Customize Server
? Please choice server: 1
? First get wio user token from https://wio.seeed.io/login
? Then enter token: xxxxxxxxxxxx
> Successfully completed login! Check state, see 'wio state'
```

and run `wio setup`.

```
 % wio setup
> Setup is easy! Let's get started...

! PROTIP: Hold the Configure button ~4s into Configure Mode!
! PROTIP: Please make sure you are connected to the Server

? Would you like continue? [Y/n]: y
0.) Wio Link v1.0
1.) Wio Node v1.0
? Please choice the board type: 1

! PROTIP: Wireless setup of Wio!
! PROTIP: You need manually change your Wi-Fi network to Wio's network.
! PROTIP: You will lose your connection to the internet periodically.

? Please connect to the Wio_* network now. Press enter when ready: y
? Would you like to manually enter your Wi-Fi network configuration? [y/N]: y
> Please enter the SSID of your Wi-Fi network: TANEMAKI
> Please enter your Wi-Fi network password (leave blank for none): ilovemoguko
> Please enter the name of a device will be created: winnode_tetsu
> Here's what we're going to send to the Wio:

> Wi-Fi network: xxxxxxx
> Password: xxxxxxxxx
> Device name: winnode_ironsand

? Would you like to continue with the information shown above? [Y/n]: y
```

But `wio list` shows no device.

```
% wio list
No Wio devices could be found.
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out the cause of error.

I was trying to connect to 5.0GHz wifi network, but Wio node can only connect 2.4GHz network.

I just need to connect 2.4GHz WiFi. That's all.